# Home directory shell

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing below script do create the home directory for the specific users and need to give ownership too.

Is the below the specified variable called userid will valid after home directory creation? gettig error when i run this script but home directory getting created but not chown

```
#!/bin/bash
#################### How to Check folder already exits or not #####################################################
read -p "Enter user id: " userid
if [ -d /tmp/$userid ]; then
echo -e "\e[31mFOLDER ALREADY EXISTS\e[0m"
else
mkdir /tmp/$userid
chown -R $userid:root $userid
fi
```

Comment: You're trying to run `chown` on `$userid` and not on `/tmp/$userid`.

Comment: Enter user id: user
chown: invalid user: ‘/tmp/user:root’
[root@lab Bash-Scripting]#

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the *second* instance of `$userid` with the directory name. So replace:

```
chown -R $userid:root $userid
```

with:

```
chown -R $userid:root /tmp/$userid
```

Comment: #!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter user id: " userid

if [ -d /tmp/$userid ]; then

echo -e "\e[31mFOLDER ALREADY EXISTS\e[0m"

else

mkdir /tmp/$userid

chown -R $userid:root /tmp/$userid

fi

Still getting invalid userid :(

Comment: Does the `$userid` you provided to the script exist on the system?

Comment: In order for `chown` to correctly assign a userid and groupid to a file, the user must already exist on the system. You can check if a user exists already by running `id -u someusername`, and it will tell you if there is no such user.  If not, use the `useradd` command to create one.

Comment: Thanks Michael, user id was not created.